How do I write a Dockerfile for two ROS2 Jazzy containers, one desktop, one deploy?
I don't know if this is even a sensible question. I would like to have a development ROS2 environment on my desktop and a deploy environment for the robot. I figure I use Docker containers to guarantee sameness. My development desktop is a Windows 11 machine, and I want jazzy-desktop on it, the robot will for now get a Raspberry 5, so I want jazzy-core on it. Is a Docker Compose approach the right way, and how would that look like, or do I control this via args to docker build?
